# Implemented Jaccard distance into ANTLR to find similarity of java code

Tags: java

After a while, I was successfully able to get an unique id from a file .java using ANTLR. And then I divide that unique id to 4-gram using N-gram, thanks to ANTLR. This is my code:

```
public void runAlgoritma(File mainFile, List<String> fileJlist)
 BufferedReader in = null;
 try {
     in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileUtama.getAbsolutePath()));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
 final Antlr3JavaLexer lexer = new Antlr3JavaLexer();
 lexer.preserveWhitespacesAndComments = false;

 try {
   lexer.setCharStream(new ANTLRReaderStream(in));
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

 final CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream();
 tokens.setTokenSource(lexer);
    tokens.LT(10); // paksa force load

    Antlr3JavaParser parser = new Antlr3JavaParser(tokens);

    StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder();
    List tokenList = tokens.getTokens();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokenList.size(); i++) {          
        org.antlr.runtime.Token token = (org.antlr.runtime.Token) tokenList.get(i);
        int text = token.getType();
        sbr.append(text);
    }


    String mainFile = sbr.toString();
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (String term : new NgramAnalyzer(4).analyzer(mainFile)) {

        stringBuffer.append(term + "\n");

    }
    System.out.println(stringBuffer);
```

I was wondering, How can I compare two java source codes using jaccard similiarity from the n-gram that I have made ?

Comment: This is really beyond the scope of ANTLR. Once you have the n-grams or bag of words, you can apply the similarity measure. The real question is what are the elements / features in the vectors you are comparing. Still, that would be a function of the trees produced by ANTLR and up to you.

Comment: have you an example Mr.ANTLR Guy to implemented this similiarity measure ?

Comment: nope. beyond the scope of my work, I'm afraid. Look for work in software metrics literature.